# Force password change on first login (Django)

Tags: django, authentication

A client requires the ability for managers to add users to a company (with a random one time password) where the user must change their password before accessing anything. I am developing the app in Django 2.2

I made a custom user, replacing username with an email address and I added a change_password bool flag to the user. My change_password form/function works properly, but redirecting does not.

urls.py

```py
path('change-password/', views.change_password, name='change-password'),
```

views.py

```py
class Login(LoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # form is valid (= correct password), now check if user requires to set own password
        if form.get_user().change_password:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('change-password'))
        else:
            auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            request.user.change_password = False
            request.user.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, request.user)
            return redirect(reverse('user_view'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('change-password'))
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'users/change_password.html', args)
```

The expected behavior is to redirect to change-password if the change_password flag is True, however, while the app does redirect to change-password, upon Submission the following error is thrown:

NotImplementedError: Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser.

If I add the decorator @login_required to my change_password function this error goes away, however, I am redirected back to the login page with the URL: users/login/?next=/users/change-password/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `form_valid` method you are calling `form.get_user()` which authenticates/gets the user and checks for the `change_password` correctly, but it does not log the user in, meaning that the user making the requests is still anonymous to the system. So while the user gets redirected they are not authenticated, which means that the `request.user` objects is of type `AnonymousUser` which does not live in the database hence the *Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser* error.

And when you use the `@login_required` decorator the user gets redirected to the login page because it is not a logged in user and the decorator requires the user to be logged in to see the view it is decorating.

The URL that you see `users/login/?next=/users/change-password/` is basically how the `login_required` decorator works and it is doing two things:
1. redirect anonymous user to the login page (the `users/login` part of the URL)
2. once they have successfully logged in redirect them back from where they came from (`?next=/users/change-password/`)

My suggestion is that you pass the username of the user that tried to log in but has to change their password to the `change_password` view and have a form waiting for the user there that asks for the current password, new one and a confirmation of the new password. It is the simplest way to do what you want to do, but you will have to confirm that the users current password is correct again though.

Sorry for the confusing first answer, I didn't read the question right the first time, hopefully this makes more sense :)

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I simply added login(self.request, user) before I redirected the user to the change-password page and everything works now!

Comment: Actually you might wanna be careful about that approach if you want to *force* a password change because once you've logged them in (and redirected to `change_password`) they are logged in and can probably browse around your website without ever changing the password.

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks! I just passed the user email by a session variable.